# ActivityViewController Sharing Image not showing for LinkedIn & WhatsApp

Tags: ios, swift, share, uiactivityviewcontroller, swift4.2

I Created and extension for sharing text along with Image.

Here is the extension class

```
extension UIViewController {

     func shareScreen(shareText:String?,shareImage:UIImage?){

        var objectsToShare = [AnyObject]()

        if let shareTextObj = shareText{
            objectsToShare.append(shareTextObj as AnyObject)
        }

        if let shareImageObj = shareImage{
            objectsToShare.append(shareImageObj)
        }

        if shareText != nil || shareImage != nil{
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            print("There is nothing to share")
        }
    }
}
```

share if its contains images only.

```
guard loadImage == nil else {
    self.shareScreen(shareText: "AppName", shareImage: loadImage)
    return
}
```

For Other share accessories link (Message,Email,Skype,Facebook) it worked.

When Try to share via (LinkedIn & WhatsApp) the image is not showing?

The above code which I tried, Can any one let me know is there any provision to share text along with Image including with linkedIn & WhatsApp.

Comment: WhatsApp not support both text with image. it's like a restriction from WhatsApp. you can only share text or only image but not both.

Comment: How to set both?  is there way to do that?

Comment: No there is no another way to set this.